# Is it possible to set up role based security filesystem on linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

Is there any way to currently set up a role based access control (RBAC) for filesystem on any OS that is based on linux kernel, or this would require a special filesystem or modifications of linux kernel?

By RBAC I mean something like what is available under NTFS. Linux kernel by default support only DAC, compliant with POSIX, but I think it would be interesting to have a possibility to define unlimited number of access entries for any number of roles per file on linux kernel, so that for example for a file /var/blah

- user Bob can read and write to that file
- user John can only read that file
- group admins can read, write and execute it
- group backup can only read it
- group system can read and execute it

and so on...

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; belongs on [su] or possibly [sf]

Answer (score 1):

If you use ACLs, it is possible as well.

See

```
man getfacl
man setfacl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into SeLinux which implements MAC on linux. This is another security mechanism under linux apart from DAC. I don't have any handly link right now but simple google search for RBAC Selinux may give you results which you are looking for.